# Output( ) from a Set class with Singly Linked List Hash Table

Tags: java, set, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I have code that I have been working on going on 10 hours now, and for the life of me, I am unable to get the output( ) of my Set.java to work. Unfortunately I am not allowed to just import the Iterator or `HashTable` classes from java library.  Any ideas or advice would really help.

```
public class SLL {
  public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public Node() {
        data = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(int newData, Node linkValue) {
        data = newData;
        next = linkValue;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getLink() {
        return next;
    }
  } // End of Node inner class

  private Node head;

  public SLL() {
    head = null;
  }

  public void addToStart(int itemData) {
    head = new Node(itemData, head);
  }

  public boolean contains(int item) {
    return (find(item) != null);
  }

  /**
   * Finds the first node containing the target item, and returns a reference
   * to that node. If target is not in the list, null is returned.
   */
  public Node find(int target) {
    Node position = head;
    int itemAtPosition;
    while (position != null) {
        itemAtPosition = position.data;
        if (itemAtPosition == target) {
            return position;
        }
        position = position.next;
    }
    return null; // target was not found
  }

  public void outputList() {
    Node position = head;
    while (position != null) {
        System.out.print(position.data + "  ");
        position = position.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This is the class that I have been working on:

```
public class Set {
  private SLL[] hashArray; // DO NOT MODIFY THIS LINE
  private int size = 10; // DO NOT MODIFY THIS LINE

  // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD
  public Set() {
    hashArray = new SLL[size];
  }

  // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD
  private int computeHash(int s) {
    return s % size;
  }

  // COMPLETE BELOW

  public void add(int x)
  {
    int hash = computeHash(x);  // Get hash value
    SLL list = hashArray[hash];
    if(hashArray[hash] == null)
      hashArray[hash] = new SLL();

     else if(!list.contains(x));
     {
       // Only add the target if it's not already
       // on the list.
       hashArray[hash].addToStart(x);
     }

  }

  public void output()
  {
        SLL tmp = new SLL();
        SLL.Node temp = tmp.head;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(temp == null)
                //I think a new instance needs to be created
            while(temp.getLink() != null)
            {
                System.out.println(i + temp.getData() + toString() + " ");
            }
        }
  }
}
```

And this is the tester it should work with:

```
public class Tester{
  // Have this method to display your name, instead.
  static void displayName(){
    System.out.println("Program written by Tony.\n");
  }

  // DO NOT MODIFY THE MAIN METHOD
  public static void main(String[] args){
    displayName();
    Set set1 = new Set();
    Set set2 = new Set();

    set1.add(3);
    set1.add(3);
    set1.add(13);
    set1.add(23);
    set1.add(4);
    set1.add(5);

    set2.add(15);
    set2.add(6);
    set2.add(6);

    System.out.println("Contents of set 'set1': ");
    set1.output();
    System.out.println("Contents of set 'set2': ");
    set2.output();
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what? Is that your minimal code that explains your trouble?

Comment: Updqte your question to describe what `output()` should do, then think about the first two lines of your implementation

Comment: @NamshubWriter well the output ( ) should iterate through and print out the value of data added and when I changed it to the output ( ) listed below, it prints the address location

Comment: @TonyPall so if `Set.output()` should print out the values of the set, why doesn't it reference `hashArray`?

Comment: @NamshubWriter  Honestly I don't know how I would reference hashArray and have it iterate through and print the actual data (the numbers added from the tester).

Comment: I seem to be able to do it using the Enumerator or even the Iterator, but am not clear on how I can do it without using those two imports.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced". Besides, "any and all help" includes the case of "no help at all", which is probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the entries in your hash array, and for each non-null entry, iterate through the linked list:

```
public void output() {
  for (int i = 0; i < hashArray.length; i++) {
    if (hahArray[i] != null) {
      hashArray[i].outputList();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop as below:

```
 if(temp == null)
     //I think a new instance needs to be created
     while(temp.getLink() != null)
     {
         System.out.println(i + temp.getData() + toString() + " ");
     }
```

You should be checking `temp != null` and you are not moving your node from one to other to traverse over each elements. So you should change it to:

```
while(temp != null) {
    System.out.println(temp.getData() + " ");
    temp = temp.getLink();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So changing the output( ) a bit to

```
public void output()
    {
        SLL tmp = new SLL();
        SLL.Node temp = tmp.head;
        for (SLL s : hashArray) {
        System.out.println(toString() + " " + s);}
    }
```

It still only prints "Programmed by Tony"
and "Contents of set 1:"  "Contents of set 2: "  without the actual set data?